# How to run old Xcode based project to latest Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode10, xcode3.2

I have old project built in xcode 3.2 now is it possible to run it in xcode 10. Have tried to convert to modern objective c syntax but fails it says "No source changes necessary".[image]

Please guide.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to manually update everything

Comment: why so @AndreyChernukha

Comment: because Xcode is obviously unable to do this as it thinks that no changes are necessary

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Can you guide generally what steps are required to get this done

Comment: Means even if have to do manually what needs to be done, means how to get started

Comment: Xcode 3 is so old, I have never worked with it. Also I don't know anything about the project itself. So my advice is general only - first try to build it, it will generate errors, you have to fix them all. Once you've done that you run it on a device and I'm pretty sure it will crash and/or work not as intended, so you will have to debug it and figure out what's wrong